# How to duplicate an object with all the unapplied modifiers (made with BoxCutter)

Tags: modeling

Note I m using  Boxcutter  but it should no be any difference.
I created an object i want to repeat N times.

I select it and Shift-D so i create a copy (should be linked) but in object mode this copy is completely clean without any of the booleans of the original even if it has all the list of the modifiers that the original has. ( U know boxcutter the cuts are only visible in object mode).i tried after that even CTRL -L but  with objects data but no success.

I want to keep all the modifiers not applied since i want to modify further the object.
Is there a way or should i apply the modifiers and then duplicate the object ( or save in a file and link frpom it)??

Comment: you need to first apply your modifiers, you won't be able to apply modifiers on linked duplications. By the way, the shortcut for linked duplication is alt D, not shift D

Comment: thx!  yes alt D  i will do so